# How to change the numbering in a subsection?

Tags: numbering

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.3}

\end{document}
```

I would like the subsections `2.1` to `2.3` to be numbered `A, B` and `C` insetead, but don't want to change the numbering of subsections `1.1` and `1.2`. Is that possible? And if it is, how?

Please keep the trick it as simple as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, for instance?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\section{Section 2}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.3}

\end{document}
```

[image: sections]

Comment: You Sir are my MAN! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sure!